# C++ templates: how to determine if a type is suitable for subclassing

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Let's say I have some templated class depending on type `T`.  `T` could be almost anything: `int`, `int*`, `pair <int, int>` or `struct lol`; it cannot be `void`, a reference or anything cv-qualified though.  For some optimization I need to know if I can subclass `T`.  So, I'd need some trait type `is_subclassable`, determined as a logical combination of basic traits or through some SFINAE tricks.

In the original example, `int` and `int*` are not subclassable, while `pair <int, int>` and `struct lol` are.

**EDIT**: As litb pointed out below, unions are also not subclassable and `T` can be a union type as well.

How do I write the trait type I need?

Comment: Hmm. Would [is_class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982638.aspx) be sufficient?  Not sure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to determine whether it is a non-union class. There is no way known to me to do that (and boost hasn't found a way either). If you can live with union cases false positives, you can use a `is_class`.

```
template<typename> struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct is_class { static bool const value = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_class<T, typename void_<int T::*>::type> { 
  static bool const value = true; 
};
```

Boost has an [`is_union`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_union.html) that uses compiler-specific builtins though, which will help you here. `is_class` (which boost also provides) combined with `is_union` will solve your problem.

Comment: I forgot the union case completely.  Unfortunately no, false positives are not acceptable.  Misses are, since this is an optimization after all.

Comment: @doublep then unless you are using c++0x, I don't think it's solvable in a portable way.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll have to make the optimization conditional on C++0x support or just drop it then.

Comment: `is_class` doesn't resolve to true for unions, unless gcc is wrong here: http://ideone.com/P1J6d

Comment: Another non-subclassable case is enums it seems.  But yeah, also not classes (even `enum class`).

Comment: @Benjamin, mine does. C++0x and boost's apparently don't.

Comment: @litb: A later standard draft says about `is_class`: "`T` is a class type but not a union type (3.9.2)".

Comment: @Johannes: From your report, "This means that `is_class` shall be derived from `true_type` if `T` is an union" - according to the standard, no `§20.9.4.1 [meta.unary.cat]`: "`template <class T>
struct is_class;` - T is a class type but not a union type.", unless I misread your report. Also, `p3` same paragraph: "[ Note: For any given type T, exactly one of the primary type categories has a value member that evaluates to true. —end note ]"

Comment: @Xeo boost does not implement the Standard. Its documentation specifies what is being implemented. It says nothing about unions being excluded, and points to 3.9.2 and 9.2 of the C++ Standard.

Comment: @Johannes: Erm, right, forget my comment. :P I need to change my view on Boost as part of the standard...

Comment: I have started a thread(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543652/different-template-syntax-for-finding-if-argument-is-a-class-or-not) to understand your syntax. One thing, I cannot understand still is that why `void_::type` and the `typename = void` needs to be same (here `void`) ?

Comment: @iammilind because a partial specialization only matches if the types match the template arguments. That's the whole point about partial and explicit specializations. I could have written `typename = char[1]` and in the specialization I could have written `char[sizeof (int T::*), 1]`. Whatever I would write, the types need to match for the specialization to be chosen, of course.