# Different template syntax for finding if argument is a class or not

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

While reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540948/c-templates-how-to-determine-if-a-type-is-suitable-for-subclassing?answertab=votes#tab-top) , I came across [@Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb)'s answer.

```
template<typename> struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>  // Line 1
struct is_class { static bool const value = false; };

template<typename T>
struct is_class<T, typename void_<int T::*>::type> { // Line 2
  static bool const value = true; 
};
```

This construct finds if the [given type is a class or not](http://www.ideone.com/lhXT3). What puzzles me is the new kind of syntax for writing this small meta program. Can anyone explain in detail:

1. Why we need Line 1 ?
2. What is the meaning of syntax `<int
   T::*>` as `template` parameter in Line
   2 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Line 1: Choosing the partial specialization below if the test succeeds.

Line 2: `int T::*` is only valid if `T` is a class type, as it denotes a member pointer.

As such, if it is valid, `void_<T>::type` yields `void`, having this partial specialization chosen for the instantiation with a `value` of `true`.
If `T` is not of class type, then this partial specialization is out of the picture thanks to SFINAE and it defaults back to the general template with a `value` of `false`.

Everytime you see a `T::SOMETHING`, if `SOMETHING` isn't present, be it a type, a data member or a simple pointer definition, you got SFINAE going.

Comment: Why is going through `struct is_class<T, typename void_<int T::*>::type>` (instead of the simpler `struct is_class<T, int T::*>`) needed? (The second compile but doesn't give the wanted result)

Comment: @AProgrammer: How does the second compile if you don't know the class type? How would you choose the default, which in this case is `typename = void`?

Comment: Why `void_::type` and default parameter in the first version of `is_class` (i.e. `typename = void`) needs to be same ?

Comment: @iammilind: If `int T::*` is valid, the partial specialization will read `is_class<T, void>` and will be chosen thanks to the `void` default. That wouldn't happen if both were different.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. line 1 is used for something which is not a class, like int, long and so on ...

for example:

```
class foo {};

if (is_class<foo>::value) // is a class
    line_2 called
else  // if not
    line 1 called
```

because of there is a partial specialization so line 1 is what you have to have, otherwise you will get an error if you pass a type which is not a class (such as char *, long, int ...)

## 2: the key of int T::* is "::*", it is a standard operator in c++

means a pointer points to a member of a class, can be both a function or a data field,
and in this case it means anyone who has a member or can work with a member pointer, this is **only works for classes, structs, or unions** in c++, so the result of that, you will know the parameter is or not a class.

btw, google some keywords like: **c++ template**, **partial specialization**, and **type traits**, or **boost type traits**

hope this is useful for you :)