# detecting typedef at compile time (template metaprogramming)

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I am currently doing some template metaprogramming. In my case I can handle any "iteratable" type, i.e. any type for which a `typedef foo const_iterator` exists in the same manner. I was trying to use the new C++11 template metaprogramming for this, however I could not find a method to detect if a certain type is missing.

Because I also need to turn on/off other template specializations based on other characteristics, I am currently using a template with two parameters, and the second one gets produced via `std::enable_if`. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Foo{}; // default case is invalid

template <typename T>
struct Foo< T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type>{ 
   void do_stuff(){ ... }
};

template<typename T>
struct exists{
   static const bool value = true;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<exists< typename T::const_iterator >::value >::type> {
    void do_stuff(){ ... }
};
```

I was not able to do something like this without the `exists` helper template. For example simply doing

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename T::const_iterator> {
    void do_stuff(){ ... }
};
```

did not work, because in those cases where this specialization should be used, the invalid default case was instantiated instead.

However I could not find this `exists` anywhere in the new C++11 standard, which as far as I know simply is taking from `boost::type_traits` for this kind of stuff. However on the [homepage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) for `boost::type_traits` does not show any reference to anything that could be used instead.

Is this functionality missing, or did I overlook some other obvious way to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you simply want if a given type contains `const_iterator` then following is a simplified version of your code:

```
template<typename T>
struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Foo {};

template<typename T>
struct Foo <T, typename void_<typename T::const_iterator>::type> {
      void do_stuff(){ ... }
};
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6543831/2877364) for some explanation of how this technique works.

Comment: You should maybe post a link to your questions on how this one works. :) Also, it seems you've taken a liking to this one, seen you suggesting it multiple times already.

Comment: @Xeo, yes this pretty easy and straight forward. But I din't get your first part `You should maybe post a link to your questions on how this one works.` :) ... do you mean while answering shall I put a link to my previous questions (instead of the code itself) ? I suspect that is not recommended on SO.

Comment: Nono, what I meant was, that you post a link to [your question where you asked how this works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543652/different-template-syntax-for-finding-if-argument-is-a-class-or-not), since it's not really obvious at first. Woops, and I just noted I wrote 'questions', only meant that one question of course.

Comment: @Xeo, actually you were right for `questions`. Because my recent questions were somewhat related to this mechanism only. So, now I have got a good hold of it.

Comment: why should we have the "struct void_" here? why we cannot simply pass the typename T::const_iterator in the specification?

Comment: @xiaodong, Basically when you have SFINAE, the yielding type should be same. For example, in this case the 'deciding type' is `void` which is used as a 2nd default type for default `struct Foo`. Now all the subsequent specializations of `Foo` must have the same 2nd type. For that very purpose we need `void_` mechanism. Also refer the link put by Xeo above. I had asked the same question as yours: [Different template syntax for finding if argument is a class or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543652/different-template-syntax-for-finding-if-argument-is-a-class-or-not).

Answer (score 7):

You can create a trait `has_const_iterator` that provides a boolean value and use that in the specialization.

Something like this might do it:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_const_iterator {
private:
    template <typename T1>
    static typename T1::const_iterator test(int);
    template <typename>
    static void test(...);
public:
    enum { value = !std::is_void<decltype(test<T>(0))>::value };
};
```

And then you can specialize like this:

```
template <typename T,
          bool IsFundamental = std::is_fundamental<T>::value,
          bool HasConstIterator = has_const_iterator<T>::value>
struct Foo; // default case is invalid, so no definition!

template <typename T>
struct Foo< T, true, false>{ 
   void do_stuff(){// bla }
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, false, true> {
    void do_stuff(){//bla}
};
```

Comment: Is there a reason you chose `test(int)` instead of, e.g., `test()`?Just making sure I understand how the overload resolution works here. Thanks!

Comment: @nknight: Reason: to make the call to `test` unambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another version of a member type trait check:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_const_iterator
{
private:
    typedef char                      yes;
    typedef struct { char array[2]; } no;

    template<typename C> static yes test(typename C::const_iterator*);
    template<typename C> static no  test(...);
public:
    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of ways to do this. In C++03, you could use boost and `enable_if` to define the trait ([docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/has-xxx-trait-def.html), [source](https://github.com/boostorg/mpl/blob/develop/include/boost/mpl/has_xxx.hpp)):

```
BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(const_iterator);

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo< T, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_fundamental<T> >::type>{ 
   void do_stuff(){ ... }
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, typename boost::enable_if<has_const_iterator<T> >::type> {
    void do_stuff(){ ... }
};
```

In C++11, you could use [Tick](https://github.com/pfultz2/Tick) like this:

```
TICK_TRAIT(has_const_iterator)
{
    template<class T>
    auto require(const T&) -> valid<
        has_type<typename T::const_iterator>
    >;
};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Foo< T, TICK_CLASS_REQUIRES(std::is_fundamental<T>::value)>{ 
   void do_stuff(){ ... }
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo<T, TICK_CLASS_REQUIRES(has_const_iterator<T>())> {
    void do_stuff(){ ... }
};
```

Also with [Tick](https://github.com/pfultz2/Tick) you can further enhance the trait to actually detect that the `const_iterator` is actually an iterator, as well. So say we define a simple `is_iterator` trait like this:

```
TICK_TRAIT(is_iterator,
    std::is_copy_constructible<_>)
{
    template<class I>
    auto require(I&& i) -> valid<
        decltype(*i),
        decltype(++i)
    >;
};
```

We can then define `has_const_iterator` trait to check that the `const_iterator` type matches the `is_iterator` trait like this:

```
TICK_TRAIT(has_const_iterator)
{
    template<class T>
    auto require(const T&) -> valid<
        has_type<typename T::const_iterator, is_iterator<_>>
    >;
};
```