# C++ compile-time class contracts (ie, template-metaprogramming)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, compile-time

Are there any patterns for defining compile-time class contracts?

My goals are:

- maintainability - in a large codebase, it would be very useful to specify and validate the compile-time contracts so the dependencies are obvious.
- quality error messages - instead of complaining that a line of code deep inside the template can't call a method, it would be better to surface the lack of contract fulfillment.

Something like...

```
class StaticContract {
  static void Method();
};

class MeetsContract {
  static void Method();
};

// T must have all methods of StaticContract, or compile-time error.
template <class T /*   : StaticContract   */>
void DoSomething(T t);
```

I'd accept:

- way of enforcing the contract at compile time
- patterns for capturing / documenting compile-time contracts
- solutions for the subsets of {static methods, member methods, typedefs, etc}
- solutions that redefine my problem statement
- best practices

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Doesn't the [SFINAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) technique serve your purposes?

Comment: answered in the question body: maintainability and better error messages.

Comment: Could you make `StaticContract` an abstract class and have `DoSomething` take a `StaticContract*` argument? If the derived class fails to override a pure virtual function, it will be uninstantiable.

Comment: That somewhat works for member methods, but not static methods.  One also has to be careful (using `final`) to ensure that the dispatch isn't virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred approach at this point is to borrow Yakk's `can_apply` metafunction:

```
namespace details {
    template <class...>
    using void_t = void;    

    template <template <class...> class Z, class, class...>
    struct can_apply : std::false_type {};

    template <template <class...> class Z, class...Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type{};
}

template <template <class...> class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

Stick that somewhere for safe keeping. Then, we can define contracts for our types as just expressions which we expect to be valid. In this case, we need a non-`const` member function named `Method`:

```
template <class T>
using StaticContract = decltype(std::declval<T&>().Method());
```

So then we just require it:

```
template <class T>
void DoSomething(T ) {
    static_assert(can_apply<StaticContract, T>::value, "!");
}
```

The contract can be arbitrarily complex too. Maybe you need `T` to be copy assignable and incrementable too:

```
template <class T>
using StaticContract = decltype(
    std::declval<T&>().Method(),
    std::declval<T&>() = std::declval<T const&>(),
    ++std::declval<T&>()
    );
```

This is all naturally SFINAE-able too, if you choose that approach instead of the `static_assert` approach.

Comment: Lovely.  Thanks for the write-up.

Answer (score 0):

This trick seems to offer a breadcrumb (from [detecting typedef at compile time (template metaprogramming)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834226/detecting-typedef-at-compile-time-template-metaprogramming))

```
template<typename T>
struct void_ { typedef void type; };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct Foo {};

template<typename T>
struct Foo <T, typename void_<typename T::const_iterator>::type> {
      void do_stuff(){ ... }
};
```

Hmm, how to weave it into a workable pattern?

Comment: Good luck implementing this technique with a miniscule number of 15 members :)