# What are the use cases of not declaring the name for a typename in template?

Tags: c++, templates, coding-style, typename

Sometimes I see below kind of declaration:

```
template<typename>  // <-- not "typename T"
struct A { ... };
```

What are the use-cases for such declaration. Are those useful or just a matter of style ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you really see that use for a template definition, and not for, say, a template declaration (only)?

Some uses:

```
// declaration only: the parameter name has no use beyond documentation
template<typename>
struct A;

// this is fine
template<typename T>
void eat_an_a(A<T> a);

// later, we can name the parameter to use it
template<typename T>
struct A { ... };

// C++0x only
template<
    typename T
    // We don't care for the actual type (which will default to void)
    // the goal is sfinae
    , typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_array<typename std::decay<T>::type>::value
    >::value
>
void
f(T&& t);

// We still don't care to name that defaulted parameter
template<typename T, typename>
void f(T&& t)
{ ... }
```

---

The explanation to the very particular case you linked to has been given by Johannes, but apparently you have found it unsatisfactory. I'm going to walk you through how this works. Let us assume an arbitrary traits class:

```
// no definition
template<typename TypeToExamine, typename ImplementationDetail = void>
struct trait;
```

I'm spelling out the role of the type parameters in their names. Now what this declaration allows, since the second parameter is defaulted, is a bit of syntactic sugar. Wherever `trait<U>` appears, it's *exactly* as if we've written `trait<U, void>` had been written. Let us now provide a definition for the base case of our trait:

```
// assume previous declaration is still in scope so we do not default
// the second parameter again
template<typename T, typename> struct trait: std::false_type {};
```

It's not a very useful trait. Now when we write `trait<U>`, which is short for `trait<U, void>`, we end up with this definition. This means that `trait<U>::value` is valid and is in fact `false`. Let's make our class more useful by adding the secret ingredient:

```
template<typename> struct void_ { typedef void type; };
// again, assume previous declarations are in scope
template<typename T, typename void_<decltype( T() + T() )>::type>
struct trait: std::true_type {};
```

Again, when we write `trait<U>`, it's as if we'd written `trait<U, void>`. The partial specialization doesn't change that (it's not allowed to). But what definition should we use when we query `trait<U>::value`? Well, first, we have to know what exactly the specialization shoud match; or, what is the mysterious second argument `typename void_<decltype( T() + T() )>::type`?

The simplest case is when `U() + U()` is ill-formed. Then SFINAE kicks in and it's as if the specialization didn't exist; thus we get the non-specialized definition, and `value` is `false`. If however `U() + U()` is well-formed, then `decltype` yields a type, and the whole turns into `void`, since for all types `void_<T>::type` is `void`. So this means that we have a specialization of the form `trait<T, void>`. This can match `trait<U>`, simply matching `T` with `U`. And now `value` is `true`.

If however the specialization would have been written

```
template<typename T>
struct trait<T, decltype( T() + T() )>: std::true_type {};
```

then the only way it would be used is when writing `trait<U, decltype(U() + U())>`, *unless* `decltype(U() + U())` happended to be void. Remember, `trait<U>` is sugar for `trait<U, void>`. So `trait<int>` would never match our specialization because the latter is of the form `trait<int, int>`.

Thus `void_` plays the role to always have specializations of the form `trait<T, void>` if they are not SFINAE'd out. Since we simply don't care to use the type parameter, it's not named.

Comment: No, I haven't see in forward declaration only. It's used for defining a `class` body as well. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540948/c-templates-how-to-determine-if-a-type-is-suitable-for-subclassing?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @iammilind Should have put that link into the question! We could then have outright pointed out you **never** saw `template<typename> struct A ...`. You saw `template<typename = void> struct A ...`. That is *very much* different, is partly described in the comments inside your link, and you can see another use of an anonymous defaulted parameter in my answer.

Comment: it's not related `typename = void`. see in the answer: `template<typename> struct void_ { typedef void type; };`

Comment: @iammilind That's a very specific use. Does the explanation help?

Answer (score 1):

1. This can create a compile-time mapping from type -> static members of `A`.

   ```
   template<typename>
   struct sort_statistics { static size_t times_comparator_called = 0; };

   template<typename T>
   size_t sort_statistics<T>::times_comparator_called;

   template<typename Titer>
   void my_sort( Titer first, Titer last )
   {
       //...
       ++sort_statistics<iterator_traits<Titer>::value_type>::times_comparator_called;
       if (*itA < *itB) { 
       //...
   }
   ```
2. It can still be specialized.