# Why SFINAE trick doesn't work for non-class type when tried for class member pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, sfinae

With curiosity, I was trying an alternate implementation of [is_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540948/c-templates-how-to-determine-if-a-type-is-suitable-for-subclassing?answertab=votes#tab-top) construct using the `sizeof()` trick. Following is the code:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_class
{
  typedef char (&yes)[7];
  typedef char (&no)[3];

  static yes check (int T::*);
  static no check (...);

  enum { value = (sizeof(check(0)) == sizeof(yes)) };
};
```

Problem is when I instantiate `is_class<int>`, it gives compile error:

```
error: creating pointer to member of non-class type ‘int’
```

Now, my question is, if `int T::*` is not applicable for `int` (or `void*` etc.) then why **doesn't substitution fail** for `yes check`. Shouldn't compiler select the `no check` ?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892087/if-the-address-of-a-function-can-not-be-resolved-during-deduction-is-it-sfinae-o for an explanation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`yes` and `no` are not templates, SFINAE cannot possibly apply to them. You need to do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_class
{
  typedef char (&yes)[7];
  typedef char (&no)[3];

  template <typename U>
  static yes check (int U::*);

  template <typename>
  static no check (...);

  enum { value = (sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes)) };
};
```

Now SFINAE can kick in.

Comment: Why to call as `check<T>` and not simply `check` >

Comment: @iammilind: Imagine there was only the `yes` function. The compiler cannot deduce what `U` should be, because it's in a non-deducible context. SFINAE would never be able to kick in because it couldn't even *try* the overload. But we do know, in fact, what `U` should be.

Comment: `it's in a non-deducible context`. Can't `int U::*` be able to deduce it ? (I know that, your answer is the only way. I am discussing to understand that what compiler thinks when we call `check(0)` and not `check<T>(0)`)

Comment: @iammilind: No. If you have only `yes`, and call `check(0)`, what could `U` be? It could be `is_class`, `std::vector<int>`, etc. *Any* class-name would work for `U`.

Comment: Can someone explain why ```int U::*``` works here, i.e. why is this valid for any ```class U``` that may not even have a data member?

Comment: @user3882729 The _type_ is valid, but you would be correct that such a type may not even be able to be constructed to be anything but null. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8597f6f225a76a4e